# Unable to view folder contents in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like to understand why I can't view the contents of these folders:

[image]

The folders that I cannot open have a left arrow key icon on them.
And before you ask, **yes** the folders have files in them.

Why cannot I view the content of these folders, and how can I solve this issue?

**Edit**: Running on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled/ reinstalled. - The issue was solved. No information on what caused it.